# Extracting values from soilgrid layers for xy coordinates in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms, extract, xy, soilgrids

I want to extract soil values for a list of x and y coordinates from Soilgrids layers in QGIS. I loaded some layers through the browser (WMS) as a test, and then selected the specific layer (e.g. Soil organic carbon content 15-30cm mean (dg/kg)). I then added my point coordinates and made sure the coordinate reference system was the same. I aimed to use the point sampling tool in QGIS, however, every time I try this I end up with empty values. I have used this tool many times before and it always worked for me.

Does anyone know why this happens or know a solution?

I have around 1800 datapoints over North America, for which I want all soil values, so doing it manually is not really an option.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.StackExchange. I don't know that particular plug-in, but you will not be able to obtain raster values from a WMS. A WMS serves a rendition of the raster, a cartogram, not the underlying raster values. You can only do that through the WCS.

Comment: You should check if the WMS server supports GetFeatureInfi request, if yes it is possuble to get attributes, but not using point sampling plugin in QGIS. Point sampling plugin does not use GetFeatureInfo, you need a different approache.

Comment: I see, thank you for your suggestions and help!

Comment: have you found a solution? I am working on the same dataset and have the exact same problem. I want to avoid downloading all the tiles for my region of interest.

Answer (score 0):

- Choose the layer you downloaded to QGIS
- Right-click and select Export
- uncheck the VRT box
- Choose the vector layer as the extent
- Click export

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding SoilGrids data through the Add Layer>Add WMS Layer, then you probably added an *image layer*.
The data you can download from SoilGrids with this method is in the format .tiff, .png or .jpeg.
That means you will get the map well printed in your QGis project, but you will be unable to extract value (through the Point Sampling Tool for example), because it's not a proper map with different entry, but simply an image with one legend entry. That one legend entry has a custom display to let you interpret the map, and may be taken for a regular multi-data legend entry (from a .shp for instance).

... I'm answering the "why this happens" part of your question, because I don't have a solution now. I'm currently talking about that with the SoilGrids team, because I have the same problem for my project.

I'll keep you informed if I have a solution.